# Mocking protected function with mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, gwt, mockito

I am trying to write a unit test for a GWT Servlet.
Therefore i need to mock the `getThreadLocalRequest()` function of `AbstractRemoteServiceServlet` so that i dont get NPE's.

The function is protected so according to the mocktio faq it should be possible to mock it as long as I am inside the same package.
So I tried the following:

```
HttpServletRequest request = mock(HttpServletRequest.class);
svc = spy(new GreetingServiceImpl());
doReturn(request).when(svc).getThreadLocalRequest();
```

But I get the following error that the function isnt visible:

```
The method `getThreadLocalRequest()` from the type `AbstractRemoteServiceServlet` is not visible
```

I would appreciate any advices on the problem or hints on a better solution of my problem.

Comment: Can you try `System.out.println(doReturn(request).when(svc).getClass().getName()` and verify that the class is in the package that you'd expect?

Answer (score 0):

Mockito can't modify the java rules for visibility and the return value of `when(svc)` isn't in a package where `getThreadLocalRequest()` is visible.

Make sure that your test class is in the same package as `AbstractRemoteServiceServlet` or call the `getThreadLocalRequest` method is via reflection:

```
Method getThreadLocalRequestMethod = AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.class.getDeclaredMethod("getThreadLocalRequest");
Object target = doReturn(request).when(svc);
Object regetThreadLocalRequestMethod.invoke(target);
```

Comment: It is not in the same package as AbstractRemoteServiceServlet but in the same package as the servlet which extends AbstractRemoteServiceServlet so it also has the protected method. I thought that this is enough. But anyway I just realized that the method is final so there is no point in further looking into it.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately Mockito can't mock final methods or final classes :(